# Can't mount USB

Tags: ubuntu, usb

I am trying to retrieve data from a USB drive but can't mount it on windows or ubuntu. I am pretty sure the disk is fat32 but can't be 100% as it is a friends.

On Windows.
I tried opening diskmgmt but the device doesn't show up and I can't get it to.

On Ubuntu.
I tried the following

```
sudo mount -t vfat /dev/sdb /mnt_location  
can't read superblock on /dev/sdb
```

I then tried to fix with fsck

```
sudo fsck /dev/sdb
fsck from util-linux 2.31.1
e2fsck 1.44.1 (24-Mar-2018)
fsck.ext2: Invalid argument while trying to open /dev/sdb

The superblock could not be read or does not describe a valid ext2/ext3/ext4
filesystem.  If the device is valid and it really contains an ext2/ext3/ext4
filesystem (and not swap or ufs or something else), then the superblock
is corrupt, and you might try running e2fsck with an alternate superblock:
    e2fsck -b 8193 <device>
 or
    e2fsck -b 32768 <device>
```

I then tried the first suggestion

```
sudo e2fsck -b 8193 /dev/sdb
e2fsck 1.44.1 (24-Mar-2018)
e2fsck: Invalid argument while trying to open /dev/sdb

The superblock could not be read or does not describe a valid ext2/ext3/ext4
filesystem.  If the device is valid and it really contains an ext2/ext3/ext4
filesystem (and not swap or ufs or something else), then the superblock
is corrupt, and you might try running e2fsck with an alternate superblock:
    e2fsck -b 8193 <device>
 or
    e2fsck -b 32768 <device>
```

I then tried the second suggestion

```
sudo e2fsck -b 32768 /dev/sdb
e2fsck 1.44.1 (24-Mar-2018)
e2fsck: Invalid argument while trying to open /dev/sdb

The superblock could not be read or does not describe a valid ext2/ext3/ext4
filesystem.  If the device is valid and it really contains an ext2/ext3/ext4
filesystem (and not swap or ufs or something else), then the superblock
is corrupt, and you might try running e2fsck with an alternate superblock:
    e2fsck -b 8193 <device>
 or
    e2fsck -b 32768 <device>
```

I tried running msdos version

```
sudo fsck.msdos -v /dev/sdb
fsck.fat 4.1 (2017-01-24)
Got 0 bytes instead of 512 at 0
```

I also tried vfat version

```
sudo fsck.vfat -v /dev/sdb
fsck.fat 4.1 (2017-01-24)
Got 0 bytes instead of 512 at 0
```

I still can't get the disk to mount or get access to the data. Any help appreciated. I can try anything on windows or ubuntu.

Comment: What is the result of `fdisk -l /dev/sdb`?

Comment: sudo fdisk -l /dev/sdb 
fdisk: cannot open /dev/sdb: No such file or directory (I can see that it does exist though)

Comment: Seems this is not the device name of your USB stick

Comment: If I take the usb out /dev/sdb disappears if i put it back in it reappears. This indicates to me that it is, is there better logic to follow?